# How to make file visible in Java

Tags: java, eclipse, file, visible, invisible

I hava this code to make external file invisible:

```
    void hide(File src) throws InterruptedException, IOException {


        // win32 command line variant
        Process p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("attrib +h " + src.getPath());
        p.waitFor();
```

And now i dont know how to make the file visible back (The user give the path of the file)..

Comment: looks like using: "attrib -h " :D

Answer (score 0):

Should be nearly 100% identical to the code you have. Instead of `+h` it should be `-h`. [Here](https://kb.wisc.edu/helpdesk/page.php?id=903) you can find more information on the `attrib`command. Syntax is

```
ATTRIB [+R | -R] [+A | -A] [+S | -S] [+H | -H] [[drive:][path]filename] [/S]
+ Sets an attribute.
- Clears an attribute.
R Read-only file attribute.
A Archive file attribute.
S System file attribute.
H Hidden file attribute.
/S Processes files in all directories in the specified path.
```

Answer (score 0):

Replace `exec("attrib +h " + src.getPath()` to `exec("attrib -h " + src.getPath())`.

 This will make attribute from hidden to visible.

```
+r : Used to set the file attribute as read-only.

-r : Used to clear the read-only file attribute.

+a : Used to set the file attribute as archive.

-a : Used to clear the archive file attribute.

+s : Used to set the file attribute as a system file.

-s : Used to clear the system file attribute.

+h : Used to make the file attribute as hidden not visible to the user.

-h : Used to clear the hidden file attribute.
```

Answer (score 0):

This is an old method. You should be using [`java.nio.file.Files.setFileAttribute()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/nio/file/Files.html#setAttribute%28java.nio.file.Path,%20java.lang.String,%20java.lang.Object,%20java.nio.file.LinkOption...%29) unless you're working with a version of Java older than 7.

The Javadoc gives the example of setting `dos:hidden` to `true`. Of course the reverse is setting it to `false` (More properly, `Boolean.FALSE`).

This way you won't create another process, which is a relatively costly operation.

Mind the various checked exceptions, of course.